Generalisation of a property for constructing bases of $\mathbb{R}^n$ using traceless matrices
In a problem I was asked to prove the following:

Let $A \in M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ be traceless and nonzero. Show that there exists some vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\{v, Av\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I think for $2 \times 2$ matrices finding an explicit construction would be easy, but I do not know how to solve this in a more elegant way, which could allow generalise to higher dimensions. This also raises the question: Does the following version also hold?

Let $A \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ be traceless and nonzero. Then there exists some vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\{v,\,Av,\,\dots, \, A^{n-1}v\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.


Let $A$ satisfy $A^2=\mathbf 0$.  Now reconsider your bottom question / conjecture.  An attempt is needed for the $2\times 2$ case; I suggest considering what happens if $\big{v, Av}$ is always 1 dimensional for non-zero $v$.
